# Passing arguments to page.evaluate (puppeteer) when used with pkg builds

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer and the script works fine when executing directly with node.

However, as soon as I build the source with `pkg` - `page.evaluate` and `page.waitForFunction` functions start failing with the error  `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

The code in question is

```js
await page.evaluate((el) => {return el.value}, element)
```

The reason it does not work is because pkg compiles scripts using v8::ScriptCompiler the sources are not kept. So basically `(el) => {return el.value}` is changed to `native code`. More details [here](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/204#issuecomment-345624945).

So the solution is to pass a string to `page.evaluate` instead of a function.

I have been able to achieve this with a not-so-nice looking quirky hack.

```js
page.evaluate(
    `(() => {
        let els=document.querySelectorAll("${selector}");
        let el = els[0];
        return el.value;
    })();`
);
```

But this gets quite messy, since I am using xpath selectors as well as css.

What I want to do is something like this

```js
page.evaluate(
    `((el) => {
        return el.value;
    })();`, element
);
```

But `el` is undefined here (in browser context). I have been trying to make this work for many hours now. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Other references

[pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg)

[Cannot pkg puppeteer app due to ExecutionContext.js - SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2267)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to get some property value, you should probably use `getProperty` (see https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.jshandle.getproperty):

```js
const myValue: string = await element.getProperty("value").then(e => e._remoteObject.value);
```

Otherwise, I haven't tried this but it seems that `evaluate` function can be called on a `JSHandle` (https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.jshandle.evaluate), so maybe the following could work:

```js
element.evaluate(
    `((el) => {
        return el.value;
    })();`
);
```

If that doesn't work then you could add these functions to the spawn browsers:

```js
// get elements by xpath (same as $x)
function getElementByXpath(thePath, target = document) {
    const result = document.evaluate(thePath, target, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    const tags = [];
    let node = null;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-cond-assign,@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions
    while(node = result.iterateNext()) {
        tags.push(node);
    }

    return tags;
}

// get elements from css or xpath
function getElements(selectorOrXpath, parent = document) {
    const isxPath = selectorOrXpath.includes("//");
    if(isxPath) {
        return getElementByXpath(selectorOrXpath, parent)
    }
    else {
        return parent.querySelectorAll(selectorOrXpath)
    }
}
```

and then call `getElements("${selector}");` instead of `document.querySelectorAll("${selector}");` in your example,

this way it'll work with both xpath selectors as well as css.

Note that these functions will get removed from your spawn browsers when they refresh (easy way to get around this is to just include them in the same "evaluate" function).